# How to assign two different values to two different variables by selecting only one radio button in Grails?

Tags: html, grails

I have this on the frontend:

```
<input type="radio" name="adminArg1" value="brief" checked="true">
    Brief information
</input>
```

I have this on the backend:

```
String adminArg1 = params.adminArg1
String adminArg2 = params.adminArg2
```

I want to assign 'brief' to adminArg1, but also 'null' to adminArg2, whenever I click on the radio.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use Groovy's multiple assignment to assign the values:

```
def (adminArg1, adminArg2) = (params.adminArg1 == 'brief' ? ['brief',null] : ... )
```

or if you're using some kind of validating class (e.g., Command Object or Domain Class) you can override the Groovy setters:

```
public void setAdminArg1(String adminArg1) {
    if (adminArg1 == 'brief') {
        this.adminArg1 = adminArg1
        this.adminArg2 = null
    } else {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: so nothing can be done on the front end. smth like:  <input type="radio" name="adminArg1" value="brief" name="adminArg2" value="" checked="true">
    Brief information
</input>

Comment: An input tag can't have multiple name/value attributes, but you could use javascript to update a separate input adminArg2 tag with the appropriate values.  You'd still need backend validation to verify the values.